# Enhanced for loop, how to return result if matches and print out not found if not

Tags: java, loops

I'm working on a java program for a car dealership. I'm using the enhanced for loop to loop through an array of vehicles and I want to return a match if I input a make and model that matches it. If it doesn't match, I want to return "no such vehicle is found" but only one time. Right now, it returns 9 "not founds" and 1 matching result. I only want to return matching results and if there are none, only 1 not found.

I have two functions `searchMakeModel()` and `searchPriceRange()`. My `searchMakeModel()` is supposed to be returning matching cars, but it just returns not found for some reason. My `searchPriceRange()` works, but I want it to only return cars. Right now, it returns both not found if the car doesn't match the price range and the car if the car matches the price range.

```
class CarDealer {
   private Vehicle[] vehicleList;

private void searchMakeModel() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter vehicle make");
        String make = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter vehicle model");
        String model = scanner.nextLine();
        for(Vehicle vehicle: vehicleList) {
           if(make == vehicle.getMake() && model == vehicle.getModel()) {
              System.out.println(vehicle.getMake() + ";" + vehicle.getModel() + ";" + vehicle.getYear() + ";" + vehicle.getPrice());
           } else {
              System.out.println("No such vehicle is found");
           }
        }
   }
 private void searchPriceRange(){
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter min price: $");
      double minPrice = scanner.nextDouble();
      System.out.println("Enter max price: $");
      double maxPrice = scanner.nextDouble();
      for(Vehicle vehicle: vehicleList) {
         if(minPrice <= vehicle.getPrice() && maxPrice >= vehicle.getPrice()) {
            System.out.println(vehicle.getMake() + ";" + vehicle.getModel() + ";" + vehicle.getYear() + ";" + vehicle.getPrice());
            break;
         }
         System.out.println("No vehicles in price range found");


      }

   }
}
```

Comment: Hint: you can't say that a vehicle is not found until you've looked through  the *whole* list. Also, you should be using `equals` to compare strings...

Comment: Neither of the methods returns anything. That's what the "void" descriptor means.

Answer (score 2):

```
private void searchMakeModel() {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter vehicle make");
    String make = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter vehicle model");
    String model = scanner.nextLine();
    boolean found = false;
    for(Vehicle vehicle: vehicleList) {
        if(make.equals(vehicle.getMake()) && model.equals(vehicle.getModel())) {
            System.out.println(vehicle.getMake() + ";" + vehicle.getModel() + ";" + vehicle.getYear() + ";" + vehicle.getPrice());
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!found){
        System.out.println("No such vehicle is found");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Java `==` is used for reference comparison while `.equals()` is used for content comparison. As in this case you are comparing the content i.e. `make` and `model` value use `.equals()` instead. Also, to determine `the vehicle not` found you should check all the vehicles first. A possible solution looks like this:

```
private void searchMakeModel() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter vehicle make");
        String make = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter vehicle model");
        String model = scanner.nextLine();
        boolean isFound = false;
        for(Vehicle vehicle: vehicleList) {
            if(make.equals(vehicle.getMake()) && model.equals(vehicle.getModel())) {
                isFound = true;
                System.out.println(vehicle.getMake() + ";" + vehicle.getModel() + ";" + vehicle.getYear() + ";" + vehicle.getPrice());
            }
        }
        if(!isFound)
            System.out.println("No such vehicle is found");

    }
```